# MongoException.DuplicateKey cannot be resolved to a type in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, mongodb

Here is some of code

```
try {
    usersCollection.insert(user);
    return true;
} catch (MongoException.DuplicateKey e) {
    System.out.println("Username already in use: " + username);
    return false;
}
```

I have warning on the line `} catch (MongoException.DuplicateKey e) {`
`MongoException.DuplicateKey cannot be resolved to a type`
How can fix this problem?

I am using mongodb driver `3.2.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MongoException` is deprecated in 3.x versions. Try to use `DuplicateKeyException` instead.